# JQuery - making image stay and not disappear like in example

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to develop a simple shopping cart and using http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager as the base.
However when I drop the Image I don't want it to disappear from the normal list. I've been messing around for the last day try to sort it and just can't figure it.

it's got something to do with the deleteImage function, I've removed bit and tried adding certain sections, could someone please point me in the right direction. Here is my source it's the same as on the site though:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

            <script src="Javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="Javascript/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #gallery { float: left; width: 65%; min-height: 12em; } * html #gallery { height: 12em; } /* IE6 */
        .gallery.custom-state-active { background: #eee; }
        .gallery li { float: left; width: 96px; padding: 0.4em; margin: 0 0.4em 0.4em 0; text-align: center; }
        .gallery li h5 { margin: 0 0 0.4em; cursor: move; }
        .gallery li a { float: right; }
        .gallery li a.ui-icon-zoomin { float: left; }
        .gallery li img { width: 100%; cursor: move; }

        #trash { float: right; width: 32%; min-height: 18em; padding: 1%;} * html #trash { height: 18em; } /* IE6 */
        #trash h4 { line-height: 16px; margin: 0 0 0.4em; }
        #trash h4 .ui-icon { float: left; }
        #trash .gallery h5 { display: none; }
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // there's the gallery and the trash
        var $gallery = $('#gallery'), $trash = $('#trash');

        // let the gallery items be draggable
        $('li', $gallery).draggable({
            cancel: 'a.ui-icon', // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
            revert: 'invalid', // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
            containment: $('#demo-frame').length ? '#demo-frame' : 'document', // stick to demo-frame if present
            helper: 'clone',
            cursor: 'move'
        });

        // let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
        $trash.droppable({
            accept: '#gallery > li',
            activeClass: 'ui-state-highlight',
            drop: function (ev, ui) {
                deleteImage(ui.draggable);
            }
        });

        // let the gallery be droppable as well, accepting items from the trash
        $gallery.droppable({
            accept: '#trash li',
            activeClass: 'custom-state-active',
            drop: function (ev, ui) {
                recycleImage(ui.draggable);
            }
        });

        // image deletion function
        var recycle_icon = '<a href="link/to/recycle/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Recycle this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh">Recycle image</a>';
        function deleteImage($item) {
            $item.fadeOut(function () {
                var $list = $('ul', $trash).length ? $('ul', $trash) : $('<ul class="gallery ui-helper-reset"/>').appendTo($trash);

                $item.find('a.ui-icon-trash').remove();
                $item.append(recycle_icon).appendTo($list).fadeIn(function () {
                    $item.animate({ width: '48px' }).find('img').animate({ height: '36px' });
                });
            });
        }

        // image recycle function
        var trash_icon = '<a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>';
        function recycleImage($item) {
            $item.fadeOut(function () {

                $item.find('a.ui-icon-refresh').remove();
                $item.css('width', '96px').append(trash_icon).find('img').css('height', '72px').end().appendTo($gallery).fadeIn();
            });
        }

        // image preview function, demonstrating the ui.dialog used as a modal window
        function viewLargerImage($link) {
            var src = $link.attr('href');
            var title = $link.siblings('img').attr('alt');
            var $modal = $('img[src$="' + src + '"]');

            if ($modal.length) {
                $modal.dialog('open')
            } else {
                var img = $('<img alt="' + title + '" width="384" height="288" style="display:none;padding: 8px;" />')
                        .attr('src', src).appendTo('body');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    img.dialog({
                        title: title,
                        width: 400,
                        modal: true
                    });
                }, 1);
            }
        }

        // resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
        $('ul.gallery > li').click(function (ev) {
            var $item = $(this);
            var $target = $(ev.target);

            if ($target.is('a.ui-icon-trash')) {
                deleteImage($item);
            } else if ($target.is('a.ui-icon-zoomin')) {
                viewLargerImage($target);
            } else if ($target.is('a.ui-icon-refresh')) {
                recycleImage($item);
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>





</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <div class="demo ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">

        <ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">
            <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
                <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras</h5>
                <img src="Images/Teas/one.jpg"  alt="The peaks of High Tatras" width="96" height="72" //>
            <%--    <a href="Images/Teas/one_high.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
                <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>--%>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
                <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 2</h5>
                <img src="Images/Teas/two.jpg"  alt="The chalet at the Green mountain lake" width="96" height="72" //>
<%--                <a href="Images/Teas/two_high.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
                <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>--%>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
                <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 3</h5>
                <img src="Images/Teas/three.jpg"  alt="Planning the ascent" width="96" height="72" //>
                <%--<a href="Images/Teas/three_high.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
                <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>--%>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
                <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 4</h5>
                <img src="Images/Teas/four.jpg"  alt="On top of Kozi kopka" width="96" height="72" //>
<%--                <a href="Images/Teas/four_high.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
                <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>--%>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div id="trash" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default" style="background-color:Gray;">
            <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Trash</span> Trash</h4>
        </div>

    </div><!-- End demo -->




    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
deleteImage(ui.draggable);
```

Delete the [`ui.helper`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/), which is the clone, like this:

```
deleteImage(ui.helper);
```

[`ui.draggable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) is the original, so deleting the whole thing isn't what you want...the cloned image that you're actually dragging though, seems to be what yo're after.

Comment: Thanks, thats worked. For some reason the float on the trash stopped? you any idea. Promise this is my last question:)

Comment: @Robert - Do you have an example page?  I don't have your images, so not sure exactly which issue you're having.

Comment: Sorry i'm only working locally, just trying to learn Jquery and liked the drag and drop. If you take the example of the link in my 1st post and do the ui.helper change you stated. It will show it. Basically images do not re align to the left when dropped.

Comment: @Robert - You're dropping an `<li>` inside a `<div>`, it seems that should be a `<ul>` and the rule should be `#trash li { float: left; }`, this should make it valid and more predictable.

Comment: I'm sorry for being stupid but what bit would I change to: #trash li { float: left; }